# c++ too few arguments to function

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void kghg();
void menu(float kgs);
float kghg(float kilogram, float kgs){
    kilogram=menu(kgs);
    float hektogram;
    hektogram=(kilogram*10);
    return hektogram;
}
int main()
{

    menu();
    kghg()
    return 0;
}
void menu(float kgs){
    cout<<"Input values : ";cin>>kgs;

}
void kghg(){
    float hektogram, kilogram;
    hektogram=kghg(kilogram);
    cout<<"Result : "<<hektogram<<endl;
}
```

when I try to compile this code, then show notice " error : void value not ignored as it though  to be" and "error : too few arguments 'void menu(float)'".
Please someone help me.

Comment: The compiler is already helping you. It gives you the line and the error to correct. You are missing an argument to `menu`

Answer (score 2):

You call the function `menu` as

```
menu();
```

Though it is declared as

```
void menu(float kgs)
```

You said that the function would take a `float` argument, but did not pass it one.

As a side note, it looks like you are trying to `cin` a value into `kgs`. If you want this to act as you expect, you need to pass `kgs` by reference, otherwise you will input a value to a **copy of** `kgs`, then the original would be unchanged. You could change `menu` to

```
void menu(float& kgs)
```

Then call it as

```
float kg;    // Declare a float variable
menu(kg);    // Pass that float by reference to your function
```

Comment: don't miss error at hektogram=kghg(kilogram); :)